# "cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)" on Heroku

Tags: python, ruby, django, heroku

I know there are a number of these questions, but none seem to solve my issue.

I'm running ruby SASS via django-pipelines.
During deployment, pipelines compiles some SASS files through the command `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput` which is done by Heroku automatically.

Previously I had no problems deploying this. I've recently come back to the code and now when I deploy to Heroku, I receive the following errors ([full error log can be found here](https://gist.github.com/adamlwgriffiths/3eb8a8bd56b62f8833e3)):

```
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/compilers/__init__.py", line 126, in execute_command
           "{0!r} exit code {1}\n{2}".format(argument_list, compiling.returncode, stderr))
       pipeline.exceptions.CompilerError: ['/usr/bin/env', 'sass', '--load-path', '/app/app/static', '--load-path', '/app/app2/static', u'/app/staticfiles/app2/stylesheets/app2.scss', u'/app/staticfiles/app2/stylesheets/app2.css'] exit code 1
       /tmp/build_8d2e04464970e15667c8f825fc387c8a/myapp-8b763976868799a3f147ac8cedbd82421efa7525/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
        from /tmp/build_8d2e04464970e15667c8f825fc387c8a/myapp-8b763976868799a3f147ac8cedbd82421efa7525/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /tmp/build_8d2e04464970e15667c8f825fc387c8a/myapp-8b763976868799a3f147ac8cedbd82421efa7525/vendor/bundle/bin/sass:14:in `<main>'
 !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
```

As you can see, I've deployed using Ruby 2.2.2 previously, but now bundler has been updated on Heroku from 1.9.7 to 1.11.2.

Sass is the same version (3.4.19).

Line 14 of bin/sass from the last successful deployment on heroku.

```
$ sass --version
Sass 3.4.19 (Selective Steve)
$ cat ./vendor/bundle/bin/sass | sed '14!d'
require 'bundler/setup'
$ bundle --version
Bundler version 1.9.7
```

Curiously, the contents of my local version of bin/sass look nothing like the one on Heroku.

```
$ cat ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@app/bin/sass | sed '14!d'
  str = ARGV.first
```

Locally, I'm running Ruby 2.2.2 and have tried both bundler 1.10.6 and 1.11.2.
Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.2'
gem 'sass', '3.4.19'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem as yours and found that the only solution was to switch out the SASS Compiler with Compass Compiler (installed with the `django-pipeline-compass` package). See Andrew's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31420009/6080975

Comment: The only solution I found was to swap out ruby `SASS` for python native `libsass`. Which let me get rid of ruby all together. Good riddance =P I was worried a python version wouldn't be as good, but I've had no issues.